# How to open the keybord when the fragment start?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-manifest

I want to make the keyboard open automatically when the fragment starts. Now my code looks like this:

```
class NewPostFragment : Fragment() {
 
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val binding = FragmentNewPostBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.editText.requestFocus()
        AndroidUtils.showKeyboard(binding.editText)
        binding.OK.setOnClickListener {
            AndroidUtils.hideKeyboard(requireView())
            findNavController().navigateUp()
        }
        return binding.root
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.AppActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
    <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/nav_main" />

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And AndroidUtils file:

```
object AndroidUtils {
    fun hideKeyboard(view: View) {
        val imm = view.context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
    }

    fun showKeyboard(view: View) {
        if (view.requestFocus()) {
            val imm =
                view.context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
         }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the keyboard does not open, but the focus in the editText field is displayed.

Calling the `binding.editText.callOnClick()` method does not give any result.

I also tried this code on showKeybord function:

```
    fun showKeyboard(view: View) {
        if (view.requestFocus()) {
            val imm =
                view.context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager?
            imm?.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0)
        }
    }
}
```

But keybord is opens only after the first start fragment and method `toggleSoftInput()` is marked is deprecated. And it does not opens for the second and next times. It is run again only after the application is hard closed.

When I did the same thing in the activity (not in the fragment), the keyboard opened after calling the `requestFocus()` function.

I have read the documentation on [https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/keyboard-input/visibility](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) and I have read other similar questions on the stackoverflow, but I still don't get the expected result.

What could be the problem?

How do I get the keyboard to open automatically when the fragment start?

Comment: try to move your `showKeyboard` call to `onResume`

Comment: Ok, this partially helped. Now when I click the "New post button", the keyboard always opens, and when I click "Edit", the keyboard opens only for the first time. 
`class FeedFragment : Fragment() {
override fun onEdit(post: Post) {
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_feedFragment_to_newPostFragment)
}
binding.newPostFab.setOnClickListener {
           findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_feedFragment_to_newPostFragment)}
}`